# Nest.js ClientProxy reconnect

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

I'm useing microservice by Nest.js, but there is a issue to me.

My demand is send message to RabbitMQ and save the message log to mongo,and if ClientProxy is connect the sendMessageStatus is "ok" in mongo,and if ClientProxy is not connect the sendMessageStatus is "fail" in mongo.

When I test my app,I shut down the RabbitMQ server and send message,mongo can get this log with sendMessageStatus: "fail",after that I restart RabbitMQ server and do it again,mongo should get sendMessageStatus: "ok",but it won't,still "fail".

That means ClientProxy will not reconnect even RabbitMQ server restarted,I notice that Nest.js official docs said "**The ClientProxy is lazy.**",so how can I reconnect the ClientProxy?

jobQueue.module.ts

```
return ClientProxyFactory.create({
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
              urls: [`amqp://${account}:${password}@${IP}:${port}`],
              queue: outputQueueName,
              serializer: {
                serialize: value => value.data,
              },
              noAck: false,
              persistent: true,
              queueOptions: {
                durable: true,
              }
            }
          });
```

jobQueue.service.ts

```
constructor(
        @Inject(CONNECTION_NAME)
        private readonly client: ClientRMQ,
    ) {
    };
async sendMessage(data: SendMessageDto) {
        try {
            this.logger.serviceDebug(SENDMESSAGE_METHOD);
            data.id = this.messageID++;
            return await this.client.connect()
                .then(() => {
                    return this.client.emit('', data)
                }).catch(err => {
                    return this.client.emit('', data)
                        .pipe(
                            catchError(connectionError => {
                                throw connectionError;
                            })
                        );
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('catch in job', err);
            throw err;
        };
    };
```

The client.connect() won't help.

myService.service.ts

```
const messageObserver = await this.jobQueueService.sendMessage(MQCLI);
                            const createdLog: CreateScheduleExecutionLogDto = {
                                ...data,
                                scheduleID: scheduleID,
                                schedule: item,
                                processDatetime: new Date(),
                            };
                            messageObserver.subscribe({
                                next: x => {
                                    console.log(x);
                                    createdLog.processStatus = OK;
                                    this.scheduleExecutionLogModel.create(createdLog);
                                },
                                error: e => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                    createdLog.processStatus = ERROR;
                                    this.scheduleExecutionLogModel.create(createdLog);
                                },
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this.client.close()` method allows you to remove the old instance. A new request to `this.client` will create a new connection:

```
try{
    const recponse = this.client.emit('queue','message').pipe(timeout(5000)).toPromise()
}catch(e){
    if(e.err.code == 'ECONNREFUSED'){
        this.client.close()
    }
}
```